# Add specific phrases from Qt framework to my application's translation files

Tags: qt, qt4, translation

Is there a way to add specific phrases from Qt frameworks's internal .ts files to my application's translation files? I only need to translate several phrases for QMessageBox and friends.

EDIT:

I also want to:

1. Bundle the phrases inside my application's .ts file
2. Prevent them from going *obsolete* after a routine `lupdate`

There's always an alternative to subclass QMessageBox, but I'd like to try a perfectionist solution first.

EDIT #2:

I've solved the problem the ugly way by shipping a .qm file with my application from the Qt distribution. I'll keep this question open in case somebody comes up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: I can't understand why do you need internal Qt phrases for `QMessageBox` if you use your own .ts file. You can specify `title` and `text` for `QMessageBox` inside `tr()`. This is sufficiently.

Comment: @Johnny, I need to translate default button texts. It may very well be that I am missing something important.

Comment: I've edited my answer after your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:
For custom translation of internal Qt phrases you only need to do some steps:

1. Modify appropriate `qt_lang.ts` in `translation` folder inside Qt SDK directory. I strongly recommend you to use [Qt linguist](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt+Linguist+Download?content=89360) for this purpose.
2. Use lrelease utility on `qt_lang.ts` to produce .qm file.
3. Modify your code. You need to install generated translation file in your app by using [QTranslator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtranslator.html) class.
4. Distribute your app with generated .qm. All .qm files must be arranged in special dir relative to your app binary. By default it is `translations` folder, but you can change this dir by using custom [qt.conf](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt-conf.html).

So when you change app language you'll get needed (translated by you) phrases.

For example, if you want to achieve custom translation for russian friends you need to open `qt_ru.ts` in `Qt Linguist`, locate there `QMessageBox` context and translate all needed phrases. Then follow described above instruction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if I can extract the phrases into my app's .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt you can load various ts files for your application, i would try not to extract the needed phrases but load the qt ts files along with your own translation